# Is this interval notation for the solution of an inequality problem correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic, notation

Is this notationally correct?
$$
\begin{align*}
                    5 - x^2 &< -2, \\[1ex]
                    5 - x^2 + (-5) &< -2 + (-5), \\[1ex]
                    -x^2 &< -7, \\[1ex] 
                    (-x^2)(-1) &> (-7)(-1), \\[1ex] 
                    x^2 &> 7, \\[1ex]
                    x^2 - 7 &> 0,  \\[1ex]
                    (x + \sqrt{7})(x - \sqrt{7}) &> 0, \\[1ex]
                    x < -\sqrt{7} \,\lor\, x &> \sqrt{7}.
\; \llap{\mathrel{\boxed{\phantom{\;x < -\sqrt{7} \,\lor\, x > \sqrt{7}.}}}}\end{align*}
$$

or would the following be better notation?

$$
\begin{align*}
                    (x < -\sqrt{7}) \,\lor\, (x &> \sqrt{7}).
\; \llap{\mathrel{\boxed{\phantom{\;(x < -\sqrt{7}) \,\lor\, (x > \sqrt{7}).}}}}
\end{align*}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Something is wrong here in your solution... Furthermore,  the  two notations are the same written...

Comment: @dmtri wait I'm sorry could you elaborate on the mistake?

Comment: If $ab>0$ then $a, b$ should be both positive or negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct, and so are both notations you used for the final result. There is no ambiguity in the first notation, because $\lor$ connects logical statements: it doesn't connect $-\sqrt{7}$ and $x$ because they are not statements, since you can't say they are true or false. So the second notation is just better to read but not really necessary.

However, as others pointed out, this is non-standard notation. Prefer to write the solution in natural language, as in "$x<-\sqrt{7}$ or $x>\sqrt{7}$", or in interval notation, that is, $x \in(-\infty, - \sqrt{7}) \cup (\sqrt{7}, \infty) $.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!

Comment: @FarrelAhmed: This is **not** non-standard notation. This is 100% standard notation and it is only those who dislike rigorous mathematics who will say otherwise. The argument that natural language should be preferred is bogus, since "−" and "√" and "<" are all **not** natural language. The right attitude is that symbolic notation should be a tool to aid communication, so we aim for communication efficiency. We should not discourage symbolic notation just because it is not natural language.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution, which looks good to me, would also commonly be written in interval notation using the union operation:
$$(-\infty,-\sqrt{7})\cup (\sqrt{7},\infty)$$

Answer (score 2):

I suggest either spelling out that logical symbol (for readability and because some readers may not know what it means) $$x < -\sqrt{7} \quad\text{or}\quad x > \sqrt{7},$$ or *actually* adopting interval notation $$(-\infty,-\sqrt{7})\cup (\sqrt{7},\infty)$$ as suggested by paw88789.

Answer (score 1):

I will write the final part in question as $x\in (-\infty,-\sqrt7)\cup (\sqrt 7,\infty)$ because the inequality is in $x$.